# Google App Script if then statement returning wrong values

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a very simple if then statement that is not working as expected and I can't figure out why.

This is a subsection of code that I was working and have broken it down to the most basic script that is not working.

```
var x = 2;
if(x = 1)
  {
  Logger.log("July");
  }
  Logger.log(x);
```

I have hard coded x =2  and said if x =1 then log the word "July" and also logged the value of x..     after running my log shows  July and 1.   Both values are wrong.   What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **==**. Explanation:

- single **=** is used to assign a variable
- double **==** is used to compare not strictly two variables
- triple **===** is used to compare strictly two variables (the types are also compared)

```
var x = 2;
if(x == 1) {
   Logger.log("July");
}

Logger.log(x);
```

If you want to learn the basis of javascript (the language used in google app scripts) -- take the  codecademy recommended introduction course [here](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript.

`=` is used for *assigning* in JavaScript, so currently you're using `=` to define your variable `var x = 2`, then *re-assigning* `x = 1` in your `if` statement, which is why it's returning true.

You need to use `==` or `===` in your `if` statement when trying to compare values. See documentation below to read up on which you should use for your purpose and why.

#### Reference:

1. [JavaScript Equals Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)